# Validate with two regexes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a complicated URL that can come in two different formats:

```
http://site.com/app_id/{app_id}/user_id/{user_id}
```

and also in the format of:

```
site:app_id:{app_id}:user_id:{user_id}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
/http:\/\/site\.com\/app_id\/[\w]+\/user_id\/[\w]+/ig
```

I have no idea how to write the regular expression to handle the second URL. I tried using `(stuff)?` but it seems too messy. It would be great to just validate on one OR the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "or" operator, a pipe:

```
|
```

Comment: do I have to wrap the whole regex in something? and then put the whole second regular expression there in parens?

Comment: It seems I don't need to wrap it at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an explicit or statement to ensure that you aren't breaking one regex mode to fix another.

Might want to try something like this:

```
/[http:\/\/site\.com\/app_id\/[\w]+\/user_id\/[\w]|http:\/\/site:app_id:[\w]:user_id:[\w]]/ig
```